# Is there a way to use OracleBulkCopy with oracle database sequence?

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I want to use bulk insert to a table with sq.
Is there a way to use OracleBulkCopy with oracle database sequence?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Do not insert into a table with a sequence.

Intead insert into a temporary table and then use appropriate sql to copy to the final destination table.

I have siomilar approaches on SQL Server - bulk copy into temporar table, then to server side processing to final destinations.